# Automatic Generation of question in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

im currently working on a simple chatbot in python. The goal of this chatbot is to discriminate some products of a product list in order replace the search bar on some website.
So im currently working on the automatic generation of question to ask to the user, using a keyword.
Do you have any algorithm in mind or some keyword in order to help me in my research ?
Thank you !

Ps: an example of use.
QuestionGeneration("colour") -> "What color is the product you are looking for ?"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this site is not well-suited to these broad type of questions. Stackoverflow is aimed at specific coding questions with a [mcve]. You will have better results if you try some things, then ask specific questions when you get stuck on a problem.

Comment: In general, advice on the best approach depends on the number of possible questions to ask. Shall the system ask for a fixed number of attributes? If yes, just use canned text (templates with predefined questions). Any other more complex generation task really demands for a more detailed description of your specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if question generation can be done properly with just one keyword. Maybe I am not very informed on that matter. However, here is a service you can use to generate questions automatically from any text. https://app.flexudy.com